# Is ALE plot value constant for observations in the same interval?

Tags: machine-learning, interpretation, ale

I have been reading Chapter 8.2 of the [Interpretable Machine Learning](https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/ale.html) about Accumulated Local Effects (ALE) plots. It includes the following formula which defines the ALE value for a given value of feature x_j:

[image]

As I understand it, the second term on the right side is mean and it will be constant for all values of x_j. At the same time, the first term will be constant for all value of x_j that end up in the same interval. Based on that, ALE curve should look like a step function.

However, this is not consistent with Figure 8.10 where the function is linear:
[image]

I suppose, there is a mistake in my understanding of ALE curve. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you think that "ALE curve should look like a step function", but let me explain what ALE does in a way that might help you make sense of what you see here. It is important to understand that ALE does not directly describe the data. Rather, **ALE tries to accurately describe how a model characterizes the data**.

The [first paragraph of section 8.2.4](https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/ale.html#examples-1) says, "The prediction model is mostly a linear regression model." (I don't know what "mostly" means in that context, but everything makes sense from the perspective of linear regression.) No matter what the data looks like, a linear regression model characterizes the relationships between each X variable and Y as a straight line. It tries to draw the straight line that best fits the data.

ALE tries to accurately describe the model. Since the model fits a straight line to all relationships, then the ALE reflects that: every plot is a straight line. That's what is seen. ALE for linear regression models always look like straight lines for continuous data. ALE only looks curved (or maybe like a step function, as you say) when the model algorithm supports curved relationships (such as GAM or most machine learning algorithms).

As I understand it, the contrast with PDP in the portion you refer to highlights how PDP relationships get distorted when interactions are present but ALE is immune to interactions. Whether interactions are present or not, one-dimensional (single-variable) ALE still faithfully portrays the relationship that the model characterizes (in this case, a straight line). ALE portrays interactions separately in two-dimensional interaction ALEs.

I hope the plots make sense now.